# Why does conditional rendering in FlatList showing unordered result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I wanted to implement the conditional rendering in the FlatList, so i used the below logic.
This the code for FlatList.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={Object.keys(props.results)}
                numColumns={3}
                extraData={Object.keys(props.results)}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                   **return renderMessage(item, props)**
                }}/>
        </View>
```

This is the code of the condition:

```
 const renderMessage = (item, props) => {
        if (props.results[item].opted) {
            console.log("inside if")
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <ResultsDetail results={props.results[item]}
                                   setResults={props.setResults}
                                   setUserInterestResults={props.setUserInterestResults}> </ResultsDetail>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the results in the gridview, but its not ordered. I think its getting sorted or displayed based on the index. Please find the out as below.

[image: output]

How can i arrange it in order? Can you guys please help me with this?

Comment: Ordered by what? Alphabetically? Opted? Your question is incomplete. How exactly should the list look like, and how does the data (props.results) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={Object.keys(props.results).filter((item => item.opted === true ? return item))}
        numColumns={3}
        extraData={Object.keys(props.results).filter((item => item.opted === true ? return item))}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => renderMessage(item, props)} />
</View>


const renderMessage = (item, props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <ResultsDetail results={props.results[item]}
                setResults={props.setResults}
                setUserInterestResults={props.setUserInterestResults}> </ResultsDetail>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Comment: Getting an error after adding the else. Its saying Invariant Violation. Text string must be rendered within a <text>. I think its considering <> </> as Text Component

Comment: I had already tried returning null. Didn't got desried result

Comment: If i removed return from renderItem, nothing is getting displayed in the screen. We need return

Comment: Object.keys(props.results).map((item => item.opted === true)) is giving an output of array like this Array [
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,]

Comment: Updated answer. Please check

Comment: @coders, If My answer helps you. Please upvote and mark it as a right answer.

Comment: It helped me to figure out. Thanks. I will do

Answer (score 1):

I was able to arrange it by order using the filter. Updated answer i have posted below.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    **data={Object.keys(props.results).filter((value) =>{
                        return props.results[value].opted === true;
                    })}**
                    numColumns={3}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        return renderMessage(item, props)
                    }}/>
            </View>


const renderMessage = (item, props) => {

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <ResultsDetail results={props.results[item]}
                           setResults={props.setResults}
                           setUserInterestResults={props.setUserInterestResults}> </ResultsDetail>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

}
```